# is there any alternative to Visual Assist for VC++?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-assist

can anyone tell me if there is any alternative for visual asssit? We are using MSVC6, since it suits well for our projects and not in a mood to move to vc.net.

I am so hooked up with VA that I am unable to code without it.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VA works with VC6 also, though functionality is limited. But I don't think there is a better alternative.